# PDO MSSQL: SELECT x FROM VIEW cannot return result set

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu, pdo

I am trying to use PDO in Linux to connect to MSSQL Server. There is a DB schema containing some Tables and Views.

```
$db = new PDO("dblib:host=$host:$port;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

// Working: select from a table
$sql = "SELECT id FROM some_table";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// NOT Working: select from a view
$sql = "SELECT id FROM some_view";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I found the function `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` is unable to return results when selecting from a View, but works fine in Table.

Given that the account I logged in to SQL Server has permissions on both View and Table, what else did I miss?

`$stmt->execute();` returns `FALSE` on the View's case; returns `TRUE` on Table's case.

Comment: Oh well, just for record, the error behind is: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7405 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [7405] (severity 16) [(null)]`

Comment: So now you've got the error message to google for